# Implications of a flat earth

Tags: science-based, climate, geography, weather, low-fantasy

I’m interested in exploring the implications of a flat earth with a sun much smaller and closer to the earth than our Sun, and which moves from east to west each day. Gravity just pulls down; it’s not an attraction between masses.

How the sun gets back to the West by morning is out of scope, as is “what holds up the world”.

The technology of my setting is that of the Han dynasty, more or less, so no modern or Renaissance science is available.

Any interesting implications would be welcome. Some particular questions I have in mind:

1. Clearly the middle/“equator” under the path of the sun is hottest and the far north and south, further from the sun, are coldest. But is there more to say about temperature than these broad strokes?
2. What are the implications for the winds? What (if anything) are the prevailing winds without a rotating Earth? I’d expect the cold, dense air from the south to blow toward the middle (and likewise from the cold north), but there are probably also effects from the path of the sun. Maybe in the south the prevailing winds are to the northeast in the morning and northwest in the evening, following the sun?

Comment: [tag:science-based] and *Gravity just pulls down; it’s not an attraction between masses.* are totally contradictory. Also, there are many [flat earth questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=flat+earth) already - what differentiates yours?#

Comment: @Trish Science based does not mean scientific fact.  You can still apply things like newtonian physics and thermodynamics to answer a question where gravity functions differently.  You can also make predications about the unintended consequences of how gravity works on things like tidal forces.  You can also make predictions about how not having a rotating world would impact and the coriolis effect, and the climate impacts of it... in short, you can think of all the ways we can use science prove that the Earth is round, and scientifically consider what thier inverse would look like.

Comment: Also, I've glanced through the the first 20 or so flat earth questions you linked and none of them are asking about things like winds and whether patterns... so unless you see one I'm overlooking, I would say that that is what makes this a unique question.

Comment: I watched a video on YouTube exactly about this topic. I believe there is only a small habitable zone as in the middle gravity is to high and on the edge to low for live to be possible.

Comment: well to start everything dies as all the air falls off the sides.

Comment: @Nosajimiki you can not do any of that, because gravity is one of the things that make newtonian physics work in the first place. There'd be no tidal forces without gravity. Thermodynamics is newtonian physics in action: Heat is movement and items bouncing into one another, and gravity is one of the reasons they do bounce into one another more in lower regions and that there is a pressure differential from lower to higher atmosphere or that atmosphere just doesn't get thrown into space.  There is no coriolis effect on a flat plane planet... Physics becomes totally alien once you remove gravity

Comment: It's elephants all the way down.

Comment: I do want to clarify: does the actual world itself rotate or wobble on one or more axes? (In other words, is the equator fixed or mobile? And are there any other planetary motions? Also, you should probably consider asking about "implications" in a series of queries. For example, focus this one on winds; seasons in another, etc.

Comment: @elemtilas There is no rotation or wobbling of the earth. The sun moves across the sky from east to west each day.

Comment: @Trish Yes, there’s no Coreolis effect (I alluded to that in my question), no Farrel or Hadley cells, etc. I agree that there are no tides, with or without a moon. I think air pressure and heat work just fine in a “gravity is just down” world, but if you have examples of where they fail I’d love to hear it!

Comment: @Fallenspacerock I’d love to see the video. But in my world gravity is uniformly down with 1g, no variation toward the edges. (A disk with regular gravity would be more or less as you describe, if it were strong enough to resist deformation.)

Comment: @Nosajimiki I also looked through flat earth questions and found none that addressed the sorts of things I cared about. I’d be pleased as punch if someone found one I missed, though! You have just the right understanding of what I’m looking for.

Comment: @Trish I looked through about 40 flat earth questions before posting and found nothing like this. If I missed something please let me know.

Comment: Couple more clarifications: what happens when air --- or anything, really --- goes over the edge? Is there still *downforce* out there? Is there air or any kind of vapour our there? Also, roughly how big is the world's surface, the dimensions of the sun and does the star have it's own *downforce?*

Comment: @elemtilas My current concept is that cosmic things (air, sun, stars, moons) aren’t pulled down. But I’m flexible on that. In any case the air pressure just over the edge supports the air above it (it’s not a vacuum). Area is 100-200 million square miles, comparable to Earth. I have left the size of the sun (and moons) as free parameters but I’d like irradiation and angular diameter to match the sun.

Comment: (a) VTC:Needs More Focus. You are allowed one and only one question. (b) Please review the [tour], Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. Thus, this is the wrong place to suggest "any interesting implications would be welcome." Per the [help], questions are expected to focus on one specific and well-defined problem. (c) [tag:science-based], despite the above debate, makes this question impossible to answer. There's no such thing in Science as a flat earth. (d) Asking for something as ambiguous as "implications" is too broad, it's asking us to invent your flat earth for you.

Comment: I just want to add that one implication of a flat earth should be a bunch of people rabidly convinced that it is round....

Comment: @Trish The very fact that you can predict things like the absence of tides and coriolis effects means that you are using scientific reasoning to describe the world... expand that into an answer, and that is exactly how you are supposed to answer this kind of question.  If you are still unsure what "Science Based" world building means, consider reading "What If" by Randall Munroe.  It's purely science based, and nearly all impossible.

Comment: @John different authors have solved the atmosphere issue in different ways.  One option  is to put a 100km tall mountain range or glacier around the edge of your world.  Another interesting one is that vertical space is wrap-around.  Another is that that everything is contained in a giant firmament sphere so that water can accumulate under the Earth where it evaporates and comes down as rain replenishing what spills over, and air pressure then works just fine because its all a contained system